# What is the advantage of using beforeEach function in Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I am learning Jest with this [manual](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html). What is the advantage of using `beforeEach` function in Jest?

I want to detect action dispatching. I think two of the following codes will have the same behaviour.

```js
describe('dispatch actions', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(Vuex)

  let actions = { increment: jest.fn(), decrement: jest.fn() }
  let store = new Vuex.Store({ state: {}, actions })

  const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter, { store, localVue })

  it('dispatches "increment" when plus button is pressed', () => {
    wrapper.find('button#plus-btn').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.increment).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('dispatches "decrement" when minus button is pressed', () => {
    wrapper.find('button#minus-btn').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.decrement).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

---

```js
describe('dispatch actions', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(Vuex)

  let actions
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      increment: jest.fn(),
      decrement: jest.fn()
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {},
      actions
    })
  })

  it('dispatches "increment" when plus button is pressed', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter, { store, localVue })
    wrapper.find('button#plus-btn').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.increment).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('dispatches "decrement" when minus button is pressed', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter, { store, localVue })
    wrapper.find('button#minus-btn').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.decrement).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: Unless you need to reset the state of the store before each test, then it isn't needed. But if the in the process of the tests you update the store, and the tests rely in some way on the state of the store, then it's better to reset before each test, otherwise the order of the tests will matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No these example do not have the same behaviour. As you can find in the documentation of Jest (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown) the `beforeEach` method is executed before each test method.

So in your first example, you only create the `action` and `store` once, and the changes made in the first test method (`increment`) are still available during the second test. In your second example, the `action` and `store` are recreated for each test. So the changes made in the first test method are not available in the second test method.

Most of the time the second approach is prefered because of independent tests with no shared state is a good practice.

Comment: Do `actions` and `store` really get created for each test? Or, they are shared globally? Based on here: https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/setup-teardown.html, looks like the state defined in `before` will be shared.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, `beforeEach` gets called *before each test*.

The other important advantage to using `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` is that you can pass them either a function that returns a `Promise` or an `async` function and `Jest` will wait for the resulting `Promise` to resolve before continuing.

So `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` **must** be used for any **asynchronous** setup work:

```js
describe('something', () => {

  let setInBeforeAll, setinBeforeEach;

  beforeAll(() => {
    return returnsAPromise().then(val => {  // <= you can return a Promise...
      setInBeforeAll = val;
    });
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {  // ...or use an async function
    setInBeforeEach = await alsoReturnsAPromise();
  });

  it('should do something', () => {
    // both setInBeforeAll and setInBeforeEach are available here
  });
});
```