# What is the purpose of `beforeEach` global in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I always find Jest-Enzyme test cases starting with a `beforeEach` global that resembles like the following:

```
describe('TEST BLOCK' () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
  });
));
```

The function inside the `beforeEach` global runs before each test inside the `TEST BLOCK` `describe` block. In this case, it shallow renders the `Component` and assigns to `wrapper` before running each test. I am not quite sure why do we do this in the first place. Are we not deliberatly slowing down the test runtime? Isn't it okay to render it once and assign it to `wrapper`? What is the purpose of the `beforeEach` here? Are there other scenarios where `beforeEach` is beneficial when testing React components?

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter Looking for more answers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using beforeEach function in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472530/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-beforeeach-function-in-jest)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have code that’s common across multiple tests, you can use `beforeEach` to do some setup before each test runs in order to avoid repetition. In this case, if you have multiple tests that shallow mount `Component`, you can move the shallow mount to a `beforeEach`, and the component will be mounted when every test runs. Generally you’ll want to pair this with an `afterEach`, where you call `wrapper.unmount()`.

```
describe('tests', () => {
  it('does one thing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    // ...test some things
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it('does another thing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    // ...test something else
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it('does a third thing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    // ...test a third thing
    wrapper.unmount();
  });
});
```

becomes:

```
describe('tests', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    // ...test something
  });

  it('does something else', () => {
    // ...test something else
  });

  it('does another thing', () => {
    // ...test a third something
  });
});
```

`beforeEach` is referred to as the “setup” phase, and `afterEach` as the “teardown” phase.

> Are we not deliberately slowing down the test runtime?

No, because you would have to shallow mount the component in each test anyway.

> Isn’t it ok to render it once and assign it to wrapper?

Persisting a component (or any statefulness) across multiple tests can cause flaky tests, because (for example) you might get a different result if the tests are run in a different order. Any state (such as a mounted component) should be set up before each test and torn down after each test. This makes your tests completely independent from each other.

Comment: Also it's necessary to understand that rendering cannot be done outside `beforeEach` or `it`. If we just did `const wrapper = shallow(<Component />)` then the code would execute during file load and not during testing.

Answer (score 3):

Jest documentation recommends [`beforeEach`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout)  for tests that consume a particular global state for each test, for example, resetting test data in a database **before each test is run**.

Note the following case:

> If beforeEach is inside a describe block, it runs for each test in the describe block.

Using the same example where we have a database with test data, if your tests do not need the test data reset for each test, you can use [`beforeAll`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout) to run some code **once**, before any tests run.